# Framing issues with Netty

Tags: java, netty

Framing doesn't appear to be working... When two clients connect at the same time I get the same data from both when it should be different.

When a client's channel becomes active it sends a HandshakeRequest which is pretty much just a string with the servers hostname to allow the server to fetch some details about it from the database.

```
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext context) {
    HandshakeRequest packet = new HandshakeRequest();
    packet.setHostname(Client.HOSTNAME);
    context.writeAndFlush(packet);
}
```

HandshakeRequest:

```
@Getter @Setter private String hostname;

public HandshakeRequest() {
    super(Packet.HANDSHAKE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
public void write(ByteBuf buf) {
    writeString(hostname, buf);
}

@Override
public void read(ByteBuf buf) {
    hostname = readString(buf);
}
```

Initializer:

```
@Override
public void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.pipeline();

    pipeline.addLast(new LengthFieldPrepender(2));
    pipeline.addLast(new PacketEncoder());

    pipeline.addLast(new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(Short.MAX_VALUE, 0, 2, 0, 2));
    pipeline.addLast(new PacketDecoder());

    pipeline.addLast(new ClientHandler(client));
}
```

PacketEncoder:

```
@Override
protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext context, DefinedPacket packet, ByteBuf buf) {
    buf.writeInt(packet.packet().getId());
    packet.write(buf);
}
```

PacketDecoder:

```
@Override
protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext context, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) {
    int id = in.readInt();
    DefinedPacket packet = Packet.getTypeById(id).getPacket();
    if(packet != null) {
        packet.read(in);
        packet.setId(id);
        out.add(packet);
    } else {
        in.skipBytes(in.readableBytes());
    }
}
```

DefinedPacket (This is an abstract class extended by all packets):

```
public static void writeString(String s, ByteBuf buf) {
    if(s.length() > Short.MAX_VALUE) {
        throw new OverflowPacketException(String.format("Cannot send string longer than Short.MAX_VALUE (got %s characters)", s.length()));
    }
    byte[] b = s.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8);
    writeVarInt(b.length, buf);
    buf.writeBytes(b);
}

public static String readString(ByteBuf buf) {
    int len = readVarInt(buf);
    if(len > Short.MAX_VALUE) {
        throw new OverflowPacketException(String.format("Cannot receive string longer than Short.MAX_VALUE (got %s characters)", len));
    }
    byte[] b = new byte[len];
    buf.readBytes(b);
    return new String(b, Charsets.UTF_8);
}

public static int readVarInt(ByteBuf input) {
    return readVarInt(input, 5);
}

public static int readVarInt(ByteBuf input, int maxBytes) {
    int out = 0;
    int bytes = 0;
    byte in;
    while(true) {
        in = input.readByte();
        out |= (in & 0x7F) << (bytes++ * 7);
        if(bytes > maxBytes) {
            throw new RuntimeException("VarInt too big");
        }
        if((in & 0x80) != 0x80) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return out;
}

public static void writeVarInt(int value, ByteBuf output) {
    int part;
    while(true) {
        part = value & 0x7F;
        value >>>= 7;
        if(value != 0) {
            part |= 0x80;
        }
        output.writeByte(part);
        if(value == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

private final Packet type;
@Getter @Setter private int id;

public DefinedPacket(Packet type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public Packet packet() {
    return type;
}

public abstract void write(ByteBuf buf);

public abstract void read(ByteBuf buf);
```

Comment: TL;DR This question might be Complete and Verifiable but it is definitely not Minimal: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide full class for

```
@Override
public void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.pipeline();

    pipeline.addLast(new LengthFieldPrepender(2));
    pipeline.addLast(new PacketEncoder());

    pipeline.addLast(new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(Short.MAX_VALUE, 0, 2, 0, 2));
    pipeline.addLast(new PacketDecoder());

    pipeline.addLast(new ClientHandler(client));
}
```

??

Where are you  getting `client` from for passing it to ClientHandler's constructor?

Comment: Client is used in ClientHandler for the reconnect of the client to the server; client is passed to the Initializer when the handler is registered.

Comment: I'm confident this is an issue with the framer because I've tested it without the client reconnecting and I still get the same results.

Comment: @Henry you wrote "When two clients connect at the same time I get the same data from both when it should be different." What data exactly the same? Same `DefinedPacket` ? If one client is connected everything works fine?

Comment: Everything works fine when one client is connected, however when two connect at the same time the DefinedPacket data is the same. The DefinedPacket data for each client should be different.

Comment: It looks like the problem not in code you provided. Two pipelines for two different `SocketChannel` are creating independent each other except shared component `new ClientHandler(client)`. I can only suggest that something is wrong in `ClientHandler` during processing received `DefinedPacket`.

Comment: I think I've narrowed down the issue to the way strings are written to the bytebuf. If I try writing a message from two clients at the same time with just an int then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. It turned out to be an issue with the way new instances of packets were being handled after they'd been decoded (was reusing the same object for each instance of the same packet).It was just a really silly mistake :P